# Ruby big decimal with 2 numbers after the decimal point

Tags: ruby, bigdecimal

I this code:

```
require 'bigdecimal'
a = BigDecimal.new(1, 2)
```

While we can have those values:

```
a.to_s #=> "0.1E1"
a.to_f #=> 1.0
```

I would prefer to obtain this one: a.to_string # => `"1.00"`

Do you know if [Ruby's BigDecimal](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html) is able to do this without having to create an additional #to_string method?

If not, what would be the best solution to have a big decimal number with always 2 numbers after the decimal point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can, but this is a kind of output format.

```
sprintf( "%.02f", a)
# => "1.00"
```

You can define a method like this:

```
class BigDecimal
  def to_string
    sprintf( "%.02f", self)
  end
end

a.to_string
=> "1.00"
```

As suggested by @CarySwoveland, you also can write like this

```
sprintf( "%.02f" % a)
sprintf( "%.02f %.02f %.02f" % [a, b, c])
```

Comment: ...or `"%.02f" % a #=> "1.00"`, which can be handy when you have something like `"%.02f %.02f %.02f" % [a,b,c] #=> "1.00 2.00 3.00"`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland very nice!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to define the scale you can use:

`a.to_s('F') #=> "1.0"`

Otherwise you'll need to use `sprintf` and specify the scale:

`sprintf('%.02f', a) #=> "1.00"`